# Static 'Core' class VS global keyword

Tags: php

I want to start a new website soon. I don't really know how to explain it, but I don't know what I should choose.

Should I use a global.php, in which I make variables, and I use a global keyword, so something like this:

global.php:

```
<?php
  $data = 'hello world';
?>
```

other file:

```
<?php 
global $data;
echo $data;
?>
```

Or do I use a static core class:

core.php:

```
<?php

class Core
{
  public static $data;

  public static function init()
  {
    $data = 'hello world';
  }
}

?>
```

Other file:

```
<?php
  echo Core::$data;
?>
```

Because I got told to try to avoid global but I heard some people my 'static method' is called Singleton and it's not great either. I can't see why not, so could somebody give me an explaination?

Comment: Why you need global vars at all? The only thing that might be global or singleton is an Database-obj. or something similar. (my opinion!). What do you want to save?

Comment: I want to have objects of classes somewhere in a file and use them in another file. It was a quick example as I have no example at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit open and opinion-based, but here goes.

I would solve this by making different constants in your class(es). Like so:

```
class MyClass
{
    const MYCONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::MYCONSTANT. "\n";
    }
}
```

Here you can define sql-passwords, site-url etc. The number of global variables needed should be limited as most elements on your website would not depend on them. Title, content, data etc will change from view to view and should therefor not be a global variable in any way.